# How to use switch statements with Boost enum

Tags: c++, boost, enums

I'm using the `BOOST_ENUM` macro and trying to write a switch statement based on a variable of the enum type I created. I get the error message that `"expression must have integral or enum type"`

Is there any way to use Boost enums and switch statements together?

I've seen [This link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/detail/scoped_enum_emulation.hpp), but it says to use `boost::native_value`, and I get the message that the Boost namespace has no native_value member. I couldn't figure out if I'm supposed to be including an extra header files for it.

Any ideas?

Example code:

```
BOOST_ENUM(Direction, 
(Forward)
(Backward)
)
Direction response = Direction::Forward;
switch (response)
        {
case Direction::Forward :
      return; 
    break;
```

Comment: What does, 'I couldn't get to work' mean? What exactly happened? What error message did you get?

Comment: Added error message above

Comment: Is there a simple code example you can add to your question?

Comment: You keep changing your code. Don't do that. Which one do you have in your source file? 'Action' or 'Direction' '::Forward'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't switch on a `Direction` object, try using `switch (response.index())`.

Naturally you also need to use `Direction::Forward`, not `Action::Forward`, but that may not even cause a compile error, depending how `BOOST_ENUM` is written.

You could also consider using a C++11 enum type:

```
enum class Direction { FORWARD, BACKWARD };
```